# How to shutdown website in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-7, web

How can I shutdown a website in IIS 7?

I have stopped the website, but when I type the address in the address bar the website shows up. Under IIS if I browse the website it says "Webpage not found". I noticed that if I put https instead of http then the site shows up even though it shows as stopped website under IIS. How do I resolve this? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Try to stop application pool instead

[image]

Comment: Hey @user854301, My apologies, I should have mentioned that I have stopped the application pool as well.

Comment: Actually I fixed it, There was a secure pool as well for the same website. I forgot to stop that one. Thanks for the suggestion :)